# Integral for area under a sphere bound by a square

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to calculate the volume under a sphere of radius R centered on the origin bounded by a square, also centered on the origin in the X-Y plane, with sides of length A.
[Sphere of radius R bounded by square of size A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALQNq.png)

I first tried to set it up in cylindrical and integrated $\frac{1}{8}$ of the volume by bounding as follows: $$\theta \in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right],\,r\in\left[0\,,\frac{A}{2 \cos\theta}\right]$$

then integrating as follows:

$$8\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int_{r = 0}^{\frac{A}{2 \cos\theta}} \sqrt{R^2-r^2} 
 r dr d\theta =$$

$$-\frac{8}{3}\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\left(R^2-r^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}\rvert_0^\frac{A}{2 \cos\theta}  d\theta =$$

$$-\frac{8}{3}\int_{\theta=0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left(R^2-\left(\frac{A \sec\theta}{2}\right)^2\right)^\frac{3}{2} d\theta + \frac{2 R^3\pi}{3}$$

where I get stuck on how to integrate the first term.

So, I tried it in spherical coordinates with bounds as follows:$$\theta \in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right],\,\rho\in[0,R],\,\phi\in\left[0\,,\arcsin\left(\frac{A}{2 R \cos\theta}\right)\right]$$

then integrating as follows:

$$8\int_{r=0}^R\int_{\theta = 0}^\frac{\pi}{4} \int_{\phi=0}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{A}{2 R \cos\theta}\right)} r^2\sin\theta d\phi d\theta dr$$
$$8\int_{r=0}^R r^2\int_{\theta = 0}^\frac{\pi}{4} \sin\theta\phi\rvert_{\phi=0}^{\arcsin\left(\frac{A}{2 R \cos\theta}\right)} d\theta dr$$
$$8\int_{r=0}^R r^2\int_{\theta = 0}^\frac{\pi}{4} \sin\theta\arcsin\left(\frac{A}{2 R \cos\theta}\right) d\theta dr$$

where I get stuck again. I suspect I'm setting this integral up incorrectly. Can anyone make a suggestion?

[EDIT]

Cartesian is where I started (and I'll admit my integration is rusty), but the only move I could see was a substitution where $g=R^2-y^2$ and then a trig substitution $x=\sin{\theta}\sqrt{g}$. So , the integral becomes:
$$4\int_{y=0}^{\frac{A}{2}}\int_{x = 0}^{\frac{A}{2}} \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2} dx dy =$$
$$4\int_{y=0}^{\frac{A}{2}}\int_{\theta = 0}^{\arcsin\frac{A}{2\sqrt{g}}} g\cos^2\theta d\theta dy =$$
$$4\int_{y=0}^{\frac{A}{2}}\frac{g}{2}\int_{\theta = 0}^{\arcsin\frac{A}{2\sqrt{g}}}\left(1+\cos2\theta\right) d\theta dy =$$
$$4\int_{y=0}^{\frac{A}{2}}\frac{g}{2}\left(\theta+\frac{\sin2\theta}{2}\right)\rvert_{\theta = 0}^{\arcsin\frac{A}{2\sqrt{g}}} dy =$$
$$4\int_{y=0}^{\frac{A}{2}}\frac{g}{2}\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{A}{2\sqrt{g}}\right)+\left(\frac{A}{2\sqrt{g}}\right)\cos\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{A}{2\sqrt{g}}\right)\right)\right) dy$$ and, while I could undo the substitution and simplify slightly, I'm stuck again. I also tried it by parts with $u=\sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2}, dv=dx$, but the $\int{udv}$ eventually leads me back where my trig substitution did.

Comment: might I suggest setting it up in Cartesian coordinates? $$V = 4\int_0^{A/2}\int_0^{A/2}\sqrt{R^2-x^2 - y^2}\,dxdy$$ You are increasing complexity instead of decreasing it by doing this in either polar or spherical coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I did try cartesian. I put my approach in the OP as an edit. Perhaps you can suggest a different tactic?

Comment: I think polar coordinates would be the winning approach, but indeed it leads to a challenging integral. Is there any reason you suspect that there is a "nice" solution to this question?

Comment: A fair question, and not really, but I'd be happy with a "not nice" solution, honestly. Unfortunately, my skill at integrating and research hasn't let me complete the first term of the formula I derived using cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: David, for what it's worth, Mathematica cannot do either the polar or the cartesian iterated integration. I suspect you'll have to resort to numerical methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polar integral is doable with elementary trigonometric substitutions. Denote $k=\frac{2R}A\ge\sqrt2$, and let $\theta=\arctan t$, then $t=\sqrt{k^2-1}\sin u$.

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^{\tfrac\pi4} \left(R^2-\frac{A^2}4 \sec^2\theta\right)^{\tfrac32} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{A^3}8 \int_0^{\tfrac\pi4} \left(k^2 - \sec^2\theta\right)^{\tfrac32} \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{A^3}8 \int_0^1 \frac{\left(k^2-1-t^2\right)^{3/2}}{1+t^2} \, dt \\
&= \frac{A^3}8 \left(k^2-1\right)^2 \int_0^{\csc^{-1}\sqrt{k^2-1}} \frac{\cos^4u}{\cos^2u+k^2\sin^2u} \, du \\
&= \frac{A^3}8 \left(1-k^2\right) \int_0^{\csc^{-1}\sqrt{k^2-1}} \frac{\cos^4u}{\frac{k^2}{1-k^2} + \cos^2u} \, du \\
&= \frac{A^3}8 \int_0^{\csc^{-1}\sqrt{k^2-1}} \left(\left(1-k^2\right)\cos^2u - k^2 + k^4 \frac{\sec^2u}{k^2\tan^2u+1}\right) \, du \\
&= \frac{A^3}{16} \left[- \sqrt{k^2-2} + \left(1-3k^2\right) \csc^{-1}\sqrt{k^2-1} + 2k^3\tan^{-1}\frac k{\sqrt{k^2-2}}\right]
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Many thanks, madam or sir!

Comment: @DavidMcWright I would suggest you to read [Code of Conduct](https://math.stackexchange.com/conduct) and use gender-neutral language.